# Bootstrap buttons don't work in modal containing iframe - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

This is a weird one.
Bootstrap 3, Chrome 60

I have a popup modal that contains an iframe and then 2 buttons below the iframe. On hundreds of computers, the buttons and everything work fine. But on only 2 laptops of 2 customers who work together, the buttons don't work. Nothing happens if you click on them. No mouseover reaction, etc. They act as though they are disabled (but don't have the appearance of being disabled).  One of the buttons is link/anchor-based, the other is an actual button. It doesn't seem to make a difference.
If I remove the iframe, the buttons work fine. I was wondering if it was the actual content of the iframe that was causing a problem, so I tried deleting all the content out of the page that the iframe was loading. That didn't have an effect either. Only removing the iframe tag helps.

Out of hundreds of people, only 2 people that work together with 2 laptops have this problem. Unfortunately, I was only able to remote in to one of the laptops for about 20 minutes. So now I have to try to troubleshoot this without being able to reproduce it. 
I wish I had tried just doing a regular non-bootstrap button, but had to get off before I thought of it.

Any idea what might cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do either of the 2 customers have any Adblocking software installed? It could be down to overly intrusive Adblock.

Comment: Good question. I did ask about A/V software, but not adblock. I'll try asking that tomorrow. Thanks!